# Windows 7 permissions and Samba domain

Tags: windows-7, permissions, samba

I'm the main desktop support in an office of mixed MacOS and WinXp machines, about 60.  I'm new to Windows 7.

Currently our XP users are admins on their own machines, and my boss is wanting us to get away from that now that we're going to Windows 7 (64bit).  My boss is largely absent from my day-to-day work, so I'm here looking for help =)

I have numerous unattended .cmd scripts that we run from a server share, unattended software installs.  Some run at login, some have to be run manually.

With the NetworkAdmin account logged on to the computer, I am able to run the .cmd files and install stuff just fine.  With my test account logged on (Power User), I cannot run the .cmd file - I get an Access Denied.  When I change my test account to an Admin on the machine, I *still* get access denied.  However, the test account can simply double-click the .exe and install the software just fine, as admin.  Power User can't install anything.

How do I fix it so that any power user or admin on the machine can run *anything* as long as it's on our shared software drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into WPKG http://wpkg.org/ and thinking that I can use that to update software at boot, and use gpedit.msc to allow Users to install MS Updates when they become available...